# bibtex can't open or find source.bib

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, errors, pdftex, texmaker

I've looked over other questions, but none of them seem to solve my problem.

I have a document and would like to do the following with biblatex:

1. Use the bibtex backend
2. Compile my (long) bibliography
3. <s>Never bother again with bibtex and just use PdfLaTeX for further edits</s>

I use Texmaker, Windows 7 and the MikTeX bundle. All used files (*.tex, *.aux, *.bib, ...) are in the same directory under "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\test".

I constructed a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,bibencoding=ascii,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{source.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Shirley65}
{\nocite{*} \printbibliography }

\end{document}
```

with source.bib:

```
@article{Shirley65,
 title = {Solution of the Schr\"odinger Equation with a Hamiltonian Periodic in Time},
 author = {Shirley, Jon H.},
 journal = {Phys. Rev.},
 volume = {138},
 issue = {4B},
 pages = {B979--B987},
 numpages = {0},
 year = {1965},
 month = {May},
 publisher = {American Physical Society},
 doi = {10.1103/PhysRev.138.B979},
 url = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRev.138.B979}
}
```

Now, I tried to compile it with Texmaker using "bibtex %" and I get an error. The complete log is:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9) The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux The style file: biblatex.bst 
I couldn't open database file source.bib ---line 4 of file test.aux : \bibdata{test-blx,source : } 
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command Database file #1: test-blx.bib 
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Shirley65" Biblatex version: 2.6 (There was 1 error message) 
Process exited normally
```

When I run PdfLaTeX again I get the warning that my bibliography is empty and Shirley65 is not found.

I don't know how I could fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: bibtex can't find or open source.bib. So check very carefully the name and location of the file. Btw: When you remove or add citations you will have to call bibtex again, so imho 3. is not possible.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Do you really believe, bibtex would report on any system "I couldn't open database file source.bib" when encountering an invalid field?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Could you give a more detailed description how I check the name and location of the file? Because I have no idea what would be the first step to do so.

Comment: Use the windows explorer and your eyes. Is your bib-file opened in some other application which could block it?

Comment: Also, check that the extension is really `.bib` and not, say `.bib.tex` or `.tex`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer "Is your bib-file opened in some other application which could block it?" yes, that was the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by file-locking,

Comment: @BlueLemon On that basis, essentially off-topic as that's a general IT issue not a TeX-specific one.